# Map coverage for CenturyLink High Speed Internet?

Tags: data-request, geospatial

Does anyone know where to find a map coverage that CenturyLink has for their high-speed internet? I am asking specifically in Colorado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an interactive map from CenturyLink <s>(from any other source it'll be be hard to find official data)</s>

**https://www.highspeedinternet.com/co**

[image]

To get the underlying data, you may have to deconstruct javascript (I pulled this from the HTML source)

**https://d1sfco99flnudn.cloudfront.net/www.highspeedinternet.com/js/2023195885.site.js**

It references the [Mapbox API](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#maps) (and Markers)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions for you, but nothing out of the box. They both require some work to get exactly what you are asking for.

[Fixed Broadband Deployment Data from FCC Form 477's](https://www.fcc.gov/general/broadband-deployment-data-fcc-form-477)
latest iteration is through 2016-06; here is Colorado's:
[CO Fixed 2016-06](https://www.fcc.gov/form477/BroadbandData/Fixed/Jun16/Version%202/CO-Fixed-Jun2016.zip)
You are going to have to filter out all providers except for Centurylink, and then match the census blocks with a crosswalk so you can map it.

[National Broadband Map (NBM)](https://www.broadbandmap.gov/) has [data from 2014 and back](https://www.broadbandmap.gov/data-download).
[Colorado's NBM 2014 Shapefile](https://s3.amazonaws.com/files-nbm-prod/CO-NBM-SHP-June-2014.zip)
This will need to be edited so that it only shows CenturyLink's data.